# SQL Statements in MySQL, the use of the dot operator

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

The following is the SQL statement that I found:

```
SELECT d.name, count(e.emp_id) num_employees
FROM department d INNER JOIN employee e
  ON d.dept_id = e.dept_id
GROUP BY d.name
HAVING count(e.emp_id) > 2;
```

I wanted to know what `d.name`, `e.name` or `d.dept_id` mean. What is the difference?

Answer (score 5):

The dot `.` is usually the table name. In the sentence you mention, `d` is the name of the alias name. If you check the `FROM` statement, you have `department d`. That means that you want to fetch rows from the table `department` but reference it as `d` (because `department` is a long word), so you create an alias.

In order to disambiguate fields, as different tables may have the same field names, you can prepend the field with the table name (or alias in you case) followed by the dot.

So in short you're saying:

> Select the field `name` from alias `d`, and count the number of employees from the join of tables `department` and `employee`, aliased `d` and `e` respectively, etc.

Comment: thank you, you help me a lot, saving me from the confusion

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept this answer so other users may know it is the one that helped you best. You can also wait a time so other users can also answer and then accept the answer that helped you most (this is optional but recommended).

Answer (score 2):

From [`Dev.MySQL.com`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> You can refer to a table within the default database as `tbl_name`, or as `db_name.tbl_name` to specify a database explicitly.
>   You can refer to a column as `col_name`, `tbl_name.col_name`, or `db_name.tbl_name.col_name`. *You need not specify a `tbl_name` or `db_name.tbl_name` prefix for a column reference unless the reference would be **ambiguous**.*

---

**[Identifier Qualifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)**

> MySQL permits names that consist of a single identifier or *multiple identifiers*. The components of a multiple-part name must be separated by period (“`.`”) characters. The initial parts of a multiple-part name act as qualifiers that affect the context within which the final identifier is interpreted.

---

A table reference can be *aliased* using `tbl_name AS alias_name` or **`tbl_name alias_name`**:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.salary FROM employee AS t1, info AS t2
WHERE t1.name = t2.name;

SELECT t1.name, t2.salary FROM employee t1, info t2
WHERE t1.name = t2.name;
```